# VS Code autocompletion without ctrl+space in html file using linked css file

Tags: visual-studio-code

i have problem with fresh installation of vs code. Im using it first time and one big annoying thing is for me that when i write in my html file for example:

```
<div id
```

and hit enter it takes me

```
<div id=""
```

but i have to ctrl+space to see autocompletion of css

id like to type and autocompletion start automaticly.

Trying user settings and workspace settings like that:

```
{
  "editor.quickSuggestions": {
    "other": true,
    "comments": true,
    "strings": true
  },
  "editor.wordBasedSuggestions": true
}
```

doesnt work for me.

pls help

this is my new workspace config

```
    {
  "editor.quickSuggestions": {
    "other": true,
    "comments": true,
    "strings": true
  },
  "editor.wordBasedSuggestions": true,
  "emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true,
  "editor.wordBasedSuggestions": true,
  // true is the default already
 "emmet.showAbbreviationSuggestions": true,

 "editor.snippetSuggestions": "top",
 "emmet.showSuggestionsAsSnippets": true
}
```

this let me type div.classname and show list of my css classes but div#idname doesnt work :) dont know what to do

Answer (score 1):

Use the emmet expansions here, it will be much easier.

```
div#myId
```

then <kbd>enter</kbd> or <kbd>tab</kbd> or will be expanded to:

```
<div id="myId"></div>
```

To use the <kbd>tab</kbd> completion change this to `true` in your settings:

```
"emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true,
```

You should be seeing the emmet suggestions without having to do a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>space</kbd>.  Try these settings:

```
// true is the default already
 "emmet.showAbbreviationSuggestions": true,

"editor.snippetSuggestions": "top",
"emmet.showSuggestionsAsSnippets": true,
```

Also, these settings have no effect on your issue:

[will suggestions show up when typing within a string or comment]:

```
 {
      "editor.quickSuggestions": {
        "other": true,
        "comments": true,
        "strings": true
      },
```

[suggestions will include all text in the document as well - generally clutters up your suggestion list but you want it anyway]:

```
    "editor.wordBasedSuggestions": true
```

Comment: sure, but id like to autocomplete my css class or ID. As i describe vscode doesnt allow me that when simply typing, need ctrl+space.

Comment: The emmet abbreviations should be showing up automatically.  Did you change any default setting with the word "suggestions" in it?  And see edits above.

Comment: with this option "emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true, i can type div.classname and see autocompletion of my css class list. BUT this not work with ID's - div# autocompletion not shown

Comment: That is really strange - that one works and the other doesn't.  Typing "div#someID" shows the emmet abbreviation and tab completes it for me.

Comment: just edited my question but nothing changed div# doesnt show me list of id's from css file

Comment: You might try this extension: https://github.com/ecmel/vscode-html-css it is supposed to work for both classes and ids.   However!, for me it only works with classes in an html file, not ids.  Maybe you will have better luck.

Comment: already have this extension, dont know if it working with ID's. I think there is some option in vscode that div# is without autocompletion but div. IS. This is big isssue for me and productive :) thanks for try and help. Typing <div id=" autocompletion is workin, with emmet not.

Comment: I figured you might have that extension - you wouldn't get the class intellisense without it.  I opered an issue at the extension repository - https://github.com/ecmel/vscode-html-css/issues/75.  I suggest you upvote that issue and open another question here.  You specifically want to mention "trigger characters" - can they be set in vscode for this extension.  I suspect that only the extension author can do so.